# Why the boot function is not an IIFE

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm just trying to understand, why the boot function in the main file of nest.js is not an IIFE?
I've changed it to IIFE and it works properly.
Am I missing something?

Without an IIFE

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

With an IIFE

```
(async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
})();
```

I'm trying to understand what will be the difference between using an IIFE and discarding it in a particular situation.
I witnessed a scenario when using an IIFE would be a perfect fit yet the developer haven't use it.

Comment: I don't think there is any particular reason. Just preference

Comment: It's all preference. I don't like writing IIFEs in general because I don't think they're are very clean looking. It also makes it harder to unit test.